# phpmyadmin create trigger error with no hint

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger in phpmyadmin but its giving me error with no hint of what is the error. It just says error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `item_backup`
    AFTER INSERT ON `item` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO `item_backup` (name, description) VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.description);
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the correct syntax to create a trigger you can refer to [MySQL Manual 13.1.19 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

you code looks really good, but you are missing the DELIMITER values below and a semicolon

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER item_backup AFTER INSERT ON item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `item_backup` (name, description) VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.description);
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: why would i use BEFORE ? What was wrong with my code ?

Comment: I think for the trigger you have to tell it when to execute the code. I assumed that you are trying to get a backup of the values before making an updated on them. It would help if you describe what do you want the trigger to do.

Comment: Actually i was just practicing Trigger from a tutorial. What i want to achieve is that I want a duplicate entry on item_backup table when ever a new record is inserted in item table. That is why i used AFTER INSERT ON